# Add storeview name in form.phtml Magento

Tags: forms, magento, contacts

I'm using default form.phtml to process customer questions. I have two stores and cannot see the which store the customer has used to send his question. Is there some custom code that I an add to make clear which store the customer used?

Comment: Are you trying to get the store name added to the email that is sent to you? Which form.phtml are you using?

Answer (score 1):

on the frontend you can just get current store object or current store ID

```
$curStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$curStoreName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); // or getFrontendName()

$curWebsite = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite();
```

hope you can use some of this code.